# Trying to understand type properties such as static and class keyword of swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am currently reading The Swift Programming Language, and when it reaches to Type Properties, it says “You define type properties for value types with the static keyword, and type properties for class types with the class keyword. ” But what static means and what id does? I just can't get a clue.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33673900/3541063) with a detailed answer may also be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type properties are properties that are associated with the type, meaning you don't need an actual instance of the class or struct to access them.  `static` is used to define such a property in structs.  For example:

```
struct Constants {
    static let pi = 3.1416
    static let e = 2.71828
    let phi = 1.618
}

println(Constants.pi)     // prints "3.1416"
println(Constants.e)      // prints "2.71828"
println(Constants.phi)    // Error: 'Constants.Type' does not have a member named 'phi'
println(Constants().phi)  // prints "1.618" when we create an instance
```

Comment: I see. Right, I recall when I need to access the property of strict or class, first I need to create a instance of the struct or class. Thanks! The simplest answer ever .

Comment: Class variables are not yet supported.