# Swift: static property in protocol extension CAN be overridden, but why?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I watched ["Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-408/) and read the related docs, but I still think there is a conflict in the following sample code (try it in a Playground).

```
protocol X {

    // The important part is "static" keyword
    static var x: String { get }
}

extension X {
    // Here "static" again
    static var x: String {
        get {
            return "xxx"
        }
    }
}

// Now I'm going to use the protocol in a class, BUT
// in classes "static" is like "final class",
// i.e. CAN'T BE OVERRIDDEN, right?

// But I'd prefer to have the ability to override that property,
// so I'll try to use "class" keyword.
// Will it break the program? (spoiler: no!)

class Y: X {
    // Here we are allowed to use "class" keyword (but why?).
    class var x: String {
        get {
            return "yyy"
        }
    }
}

class Z: Y {
    override class var x: String {
        get {
            return "zzz"
        }
    }
}

class Test<T: X> {
    func test() -> String {
        return T.x
    }
}

// And finally the property is successfully overridden (but why?).
print(Test<Z>().test()) // "zzz\n"
```

Does this actually mean that `static` keyword from protocol (and possible default implementation) can be legitimately  replaced with `class` keyword when the protocol used in classes? Do you know any references confirming that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Language Reference / Declarations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID351) we know the following.

> ### Function Declaration
>
> ...
>
> #### Special Kinds of Methods
>
> ...
>
> Methods associated with a type rather than an instance of a type must be marked with the `static` declaration modifier *for enumerations and structures* or the `class` declaration modifier *for classes*.

I.e. the `static` keyword is (mainly) for enumerations and structures and the `class` keyword is for classes.

There is also such a note:

> #### Type Variable Properties
>
> ...
>
> #### NOTE
>
> In a class declaration, the keyword `static` has the same effect as marking the declaration with both the `class` and `final` declaration modifiers.

I.e. the `static` keyword actually *can* be used in class declaration and will mean `final class`.

## So what about protocols?

> #### Protocol Method Declaration
>
> ...
>
> To declare a class or static method requirement in a protocol declaration, mark the method declaration with the `static` declaration modifier. Classes that implement this method declare the method with the `class` modifier. Structures that implement it must declare the method with the `static` declaration modifier instead. If you’re implementing the method in an extension, use the `class` modifier if you’re extending a class and the `static` modifier if you’re extending a structure.

Here the docs state that we should replace the `static` keyword from protocol declaration with the `class` keyword when implementing the protocol in a class or a class extension (and this is the exact answer to the original question).

## Bonus

There are two cases in which protocol adoption will be restricted to classes only. The first (and the least explicit) is when a protocol includes `optional` members:

> ### Protocol Declaration
>
> ...
>
> By default, types that conform to a protocol must implement all properties, methods, and subscripts declared in the protocol. That said, you can mark these protocol member declarations with the `optional` declaration modifier to specify that their implementation by a conforming type is optional. The `optional` modifier can be applied only to protocols that are marked with the `objc` attribute. *As a result, only class types can adopt and conform to a protocol that contains optional member requirements*. ...

And the second (explicit; the next paragraph):

> To restrict the adoption of a protocol to class types only, mark the protocol with the `class` requirement by writing the `class` keyword as the first item in the *inherited protocols* list after the colon. ...

But neither of them changes the rules considering the `static` and the `class` keywords applicability.

Comment: This is pretty obvious from the docs. More interesting question is whether it is legitimate to _replace_ the original ```static``` by ```class``` keyword when using the protocol in a class?

Comment: Sorry, that's again simple things (because they are _actually_ mentioned in the docs), but there is no single word about how ```static``` (which may mean ```final class```) in a protocol can be replaced with ```class``` (which may mean "forget about ```final```") in a class that implements such a protocol. **Is it legitimate? Is it described in the docs?** I think that the answer is "Yes, it is legitimate (we have checked) and NO, it's not described in the docs" :(

Comment: It may mean final, but here it doesnt

Comment: Yes, as we can see. But do you agree that the docs are not explicit enough on that point? (and at this moment such a knowledge can be extracted only through an experiment)

Comment: I understand the docs as only the `final class` prevents from overriding in subclasses, `static` itself doesnt do this. It force to implement within class only `class` keyword, which doesnt mean, it is the `final`.

Comment: No, ```static``` in protocol doesn't force one to use only ```class``` keyword in class which implements such a protocol. One can use ```final class``` as well (just tried). Also you can _add_ ```final``` at any point in the inheritance chain later.

Comment: I'd extend your answer with some details from our discussion (later when I'll have time to) if you don't mind.

Comment: No, I don't :-) I will also use it in future development

Comment: This is a nice hidden gem that I wouldn't have even thought to look for in the docs. Excellent explanation and referencing, thank you for this.